# where can I purchase a "wonder pot"?

Tags: baking, cookware, kosher

The "wonder pot" is a type of stovetop bakeware that seems to have been popular in Israel during a period of austerity. I'm looking for a (preferably USA based) supplier for a new one.

[Here's a link to a page with a photo of the item in question.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Pot)

Comment: Effin' A.... Wikipedia is now referring to SE :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My mother had a similarly shaped pan with a lid that she'd use for baking coffee cake and such when camping.  It was all aluminum and much less complicated (and likely not as useful) as what your talking about.  The closest thing I found is the [Omnia Oven](http://www.omniasweden.com/index.php?id=3980).

It looks they may be had for about $50.

Comment: That seems a bit pricey for just a stamped aluminum cookware, but this is exactly what I was looking for. The only difference I see is a lighter weight heat diffuser on the bottom. I'll give everyone a few days, but this looks like the best answer.

Comment: Here's what looks like an actual consumer-made video of the pan in action. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTxWY8-3IvI (looks good for car camping/RV/canoe trip, but a bit much for a 4 person weekend backpacking group)

Comment: It looks like Optimus (known for camping stoves) marketed the same thing in the 70s as the "Mini Oven" http://www.base-camp.co.uk/Optimus/minioven.htm (in original blue:) http://www.bwca.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=forum.thread&threadId=241263&forumID=18&confID=1

Comment: After trying and failing to purchase the Omnia Stove from a bunch of online sources, I contacted the company (contoure.com). They told me that they discontinued the Omnia Stove. Does anyone know of any other sources that may be available?

Comment: I don't know if it's useful (probably not), but in a lot of cheap kitchen utensils shops in israel you can buy the wonder-pots. I bought one last week for about 40 shekels (~10 dollars).

Answer (score 6):

My company now distributes the Omnia Oven which is a modern version of a wonder pot. These are available at http://lunatecgear.com/products/travel-gear/omnia/ and Amazon.

You are welcome to contact us if you have questions about Omnia. 858.653.0401

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: I don't see why the answer gets so many downvotes and flags. While product promotion (especially self promotion) is mostly frowned upon, the question was specifically for a supplier, so in this case, the self-promotional content seems to be a direct answer to the OP's question. Unless this product is not the same as the product the OP is asking about? (I cannot judge this because I have never seen a wonder pot).

Comment: @rumtscho It's the same product as in the accepted answer, so it's definitely on-topic. I can understand people downvoting because it's perceived as a duplicate answer, but agreed, not spam.

Answer (score 4):

I tried my darndest to find a good answer for you, but I'm honestly not convinced that these are still being made! Here is a link to an antique one on Ebay.

http://cgi.ebay.com/Antique-Wonder-Pot-Aluminum-Cooking-Baking-Israel-1950s-/350452375571?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item519896e013#ht_6415wt_1088

Comment: I found nothing on ebay, even expired auctions, so you did better than I did. Still $70+ is a bit too much to allow for my food pr0n hobby. If this is a good "baking on a stove" tool, I would think the backpacking crowd would have adopted this as a solution. Maybe that heat spreader is too heavy? Anyway, great pictures in that auction.

Answer (score 3):

for those wanting to buy a wonder pot, like me. i found this today. wonder pot is being sold in israel (jerusalem and tel aviv), sharing the link. 
http://www.carine.co.il/htmls/page_683.aspx?c0=13572&bsp=13800

i plan to have one shipped to singapore before december. will keep you posted how this turns out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a librarian and I found this thread because I have a patron who is also looking for one of these. It looks like they sell them here:
http://www.seadogboatingsolutions.com/omnia-stove-top-oven.html
Hope that helps!
-Kate

Answer (score 2):

In regard to the Wonder Pot, this item is made in Israel and it is imported to the USA by Weiss Gifts Ltd. in Brooklyn NY
Can be purchase by there site at www.weissjudaica.com
Hear is the direct link to this Wonder Pot:  http://www.weissjudaica.com/system/scripts/results_big.cgi?product=100

Answer (score 1):

Of course we still make wonder pots! You can get one on http://www.planero.co.il/item.asp?cn_4320 (a supplier in Israel). But I don't understand why you would want it, here it is considered a choice for people who can't afford anything better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at gelatin moulds, savarin moulds, tube pans, angel food cake pans or pound cake pans, they look the same as the lower part of the wonder pot:

[image: Nordic Ware Platinum Collection Pound Cake Pan]

This one has handles, others don't, and you could put them in a pot with a lid.