# How can I make crispy potato wedges without frying and oven?

Tags: potatoes

My mom lives Hong Kong when Toronto's cold. Here are strictures:

1. Healthy frying is OK. Let's rule out deep-frying - it's unhealthy and can cause cancer.
2. Her HK flat doesn't have a convection oven. She never bought microwave oven.
3. She could buy a counter-top convection toaster oven, but she feels it's too eco-unfriendly and waste of money. Let's rule it out for now. 
   If nobody comes up  anything, she will reconsider.  She has a rice cooker. Her kitchen looks like

[image]

Sources - [First pic beneath](https://www.texanerin.com/spicy-potato-wedges/). [Bottom pic](https://www.jessicagavin.com/oven-baked-potato-wedges-with-dipping-sauce).

[image] [image]

Comment: Does she have a regular oven (not convection, not microwave)?

Comment: @Erica No, not ovens, as in the picture.

Comment: So, you want a process to make potatoes crispy without heating them, at all?  Not quite getting this.

Comment: possibly related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18648/67

Comment: @FuzzyChef "without heating them" I never said this.

Answer (score 6):

You will never achieve the same results without an oven or deep-frying.

Just pan-fry the potatoes in a little bit of oil; I'd par-boil the potatoes and finish them up in the pan.

Comment: This is good advice. For more specific technique, see here https://www.seriouseats.com/2014/04/the-food-lab-how-to-make-the-best-potato-hash.html you can ignore other parts , but the potato process should give a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you want crispy potato wedges, you will need at least a tablespoon of oil and lots of heat. The supermarket offerings (oven chips etc.) have already been coated in oil even if they just require reheating.

If you are concerned about the environment and your health, your only solutions as far as I can see are either an air fryer or a Remoska. Both are very small efficient ovens, don't either require much oil, although the Remoska is much more versatile IMO.

Without concentrated heat and oil, the crispiness you seek will elude you.

https://www.epicurious.com/expert-advice/what-is-the-best-air-fryer-review-article
https://www.remoska.co.uk/about-the-remoska/

Comment: I just edited my answer to clarify that we can use oil. Just no deep-frying.

Comment: Mind responding in (by editing) your prior comment pls? Comment chains are more grueling to read.